# wkhtmltoimage: QsslSocket

Tags: laravel-5, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage, libssl

I wanted to generate a `HTML` to an image, but I god this error:

> The exit status code '1' says something went wrong: stderr: "Loading
>   page (1/2) [> ] 0% [======> ] 10% QSslSocket: cannot resolve
>   CRYPTO_num_locks QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_id_callback
>   QSslSocket: cannot resolve CRYPTO_set_locking_callback QSslSocket:
>   cannot resolve sk_free QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_num QSslSocket:
>   cannot resolve sk_pop_free QSslSocket: cannot resolve sk_value
>   QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_library_init QSslSocket: cannot resolve
>   SSL_load_error_strings QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv3_client_method
>   QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv23_client_method QSslSocket: cannot
>   resolve SSLv3_server_method QSslSocket: cannot resolve
>   SSLv23_server_method QSslSocket: cannot resolve
>   X509_STORE_CTX_get_chain QSslSocket: cannot resolve
>   OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf QSslSocket: cannot resolve
>   OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLeay
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
>   CRYPTO_set_locking_callback QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved
>   function SSL_library_init QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
>   SSLv23_client_method QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
>   sk_num [=========> ] 15% [==================> ] 30%
>   [========================> ] 40% QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved
>   function SSLv23_client_method QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved
>   function SSL_library_init
>   [============================================================] 100%
>   Rendering (2/2) [> ] 0% [===============> ] 25%
>   [============================================================] 100%
>   Done Exit with code 1 due to network error: UnknownNetworkError
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_num_locks
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function CRYPTO_set_id_callback
>   QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function
>   CRYPTO_set_locking_callback " stdout: "" command:
>   /var/www/botond/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64
>   --format 'jpg' '/tmp/knp_snappy5bb7d38dbfea18.2936
>   5936.html' 'img/temp/weather/Battonya_1538773901_raw.jpg'.

I saw somewhere that I have to install `libssl1.0-dev`, but when I tried to give the command: `sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev` I got the error that this repository is missing. I found a [page](https://pkgs.org/download/libssl-dev) where I downloaded the `.deb`, but when I tried to install it, I got en error, that I already have the new version.
How to solve it?

Comment: The linux release you are using is probably new (such as Debian 9) and using libssl1.1, install the latest package from the wkhtmltox website and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pizzamonster is right.

Go here:
https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Download the 0.12.5 version for your operating system.

I'm using Mint 19 (ubuntu 18.04) so I'll keep going with that.

After you install the package, do:

which wkhtmltoimage

You'll probably get /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage - so just copy this to a new place in your laravel project, in your case I'd make a new 'bin' directory, like this:

/var/www/botond/bin/

and then put wkhtmltoimage in that directory so you can commit it to your project.

Assuming you're using the snappy package by barryvdh (barryvdh/laravel-snappy), change your 'binary' attribute in your 'image' array (/config/snappy.php) to this:

'binary' => base_path('bin/wkhtmltoimage'),

or perhaps something like this:

'binary' => env('SNAPPY_IMG_BIN', base_path('bin/wkhtmltoimage')),

and you should be all set.  You can, of course, also change binary to '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage' - or perhaps use this in your .env:

SNAPPY_PDF_BIN=/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Good luck.

p.s. since you're doing this on Laravel, you might want to change the name of the question to 'wkhtmltoimage: QsslSocket Laravel barryvdh/laravel-snappy'

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Debian buster 10.x) I need to update wkhtmltopdf binaries to newest one via composer. Unfortunately most common h4cc bins are abandoned. I prepare new updated one:

```
composer require getoxs/wkhtmltopdf-buster-amd64
```

https://packagist.org/packages/getoxs/wkhtmltopdf-buster-amd64